# Is there a way to have Fastlane scan output as json?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, fastlane, fastlane-scan

Running this:

```
fastlane scan --workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" --scheme "UITests" --device "iPhone 8 Plus" --testplan "MyTestPlan" --output_directory "~/Desktop/TestLogs/"
```

I get an `html` and `JUnit` reports. As per [scan documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/scan/) there should be a way to get also a `json` report.

Does anyone know what parameter should I use to get the `json` report?